# MySQL rank across multiple columns

Tags: mysql

We have a MySQL table (results) with the following data

```
|nid|uid|score|duration
```

In this table we have results from multiple quizes,
we need to come up with a query that will give us a ranked output of users per quiz.

The ranking must be based on highest score to lowest score and if score is tied lowest duration to highest duration. We currently have this query:

```
  SELECT nid, uid, score, duration, rank FROM
    (SELECT nid, uid, score, duration,
    @curRank := IF(@prevRank = score + duration, @curRank, @incRank) AS rank,
    @incRank := @incRank + 1,
    @prevRank := score
    FROM results p, (
    SELECT @curRank :=0, @prevRank := NULL, @incRank := 1
    ) r WHERE nid = 1
    ORDER BY score DESC, duration ASC) s
```

However in the event of tied score and tied duration they are given a different rank

Output

```
|nid|uid|score|duration|rank
|1  |1  |90   |100     |1
|1  |2  |90   |150     |2
|1  |3  |90   |150     |3
|1  |4  |80   |100     |4
|1  |5  |80   |200     |5
|1  |6  |70   |300     |6
```

Desired Output

```
|nid|uid|score|duration|rank
|1  |1  |90   |100     |1
|1  |2  |90   |150     |2
|1  |3  |90   |150     |2
|1  |4  |80   |100     |4
|1  |5  |80   |200     |5
|1  |6  |70   |300     |6
```

Comment: Solved: missing @prevRank := score + duration

Comment: What if the score and duration in the next are different but sum up to same as that in the last row?

Comment: try replacing `@incRank := @incRank + 1,` with `@incRank := @curRank + 1,`

Comment: Jan your suggestion still ouputs the same result

Comment: @GurV that is a good point do you have any suggestions to combat this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use separate variables for the columns. Also, do the ordering inside the subquery and *then* apply the cross join and find rank etc.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    t.*,
    @rank:=IF((@rn:=@rn + 1) IS NOT NULL,
        IF(score = @lastscore
                AND duration = @lastduration,
            @rank,
            IF((@lastscore:=score) IS NOT NULL
                    AND (@lastduration:=duration) IS NOT NULL,
                @rn,
                1)),
        1) rank
FROM
    (SELECT 
        *
    FROM
        results
    WHERE nid = 1
    ORDER BY score DESC , duration , uid) t
        CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT @rank:=0, @lastscore:=- 1, @lastduration:=- 1, @rn:=0) t2
```

You may get tempted to assign the value separately in different column (as you did in the question).
 *Be advised, that approach **may not work** as you would expected, as MySQL may not do assignments in the same order as the listed columns*.

MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html) is quite clear on this:

> As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable
>   and read the value within the same statement. You might get the
>   results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. The order of
>   evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined and
>   may change based on the elements contained within a given statement;
>   in addition, this order is not guaranteed to be the same between
>   releases of the MySQL Server. In SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ..., you might
>   think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an assignment
>   second. However, changing the statement (for example, by adding a
>   GROUP BY, HAVING, or ORDER BY clause) may cause MySQL to select an
>   execution plan with a different order of evaluation.

**Demo** @ ***[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f282d/5)***

Comment: I really like this and works well, I have added a WHERE nid = 1 as this is required due to having multiple quiz results in the same table

Comment: @GHaddon Updated. how does it look?

Comment: I am looking for the same thing but I want the ranks count linear up. How this looks like. Thx in advance.